# Is it possible to access in the template the property of a model/class array in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a component which fetches an array of objects defined by a model (class).
In the template, I want to display a property of an element from the array of class instances, but I can't access it.

```
//model.ts
class Model { a_text : String; } 

//app.ts
import Model from './model'

@Component({
 selector:'test'
 template: `
   <div> {{ a[1].a_text }} </div>     <- this fails
   <div> {{ b.a_text }} </div>        <- this does not fail
 `
})
export class X {
  a : A[] = [];
  b : A = new A;
  constructor(){
    fetch data to a;
    b=a[1];
  }
}
```

This does not work for me and I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or it's just not possible. I'm getting the following error :

```
template:line:number caused by: Cannot read property 'a_text' of undefined`
```

If I use a single helper object, like :

```
b : A = new A ; 
b = a[1] ;
```

and in the template :

```
<div> {{ b.a_text }} </div>
```

it works fine without any error.

The `a` array is populated with the objects (instances of A), I can see them in the console. If I try to display in the template only `{{ a[0] }}`, I get displayed `[Object object]`, it's present

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong when declaring the array.

*Question (code) edited

Is it possible to access the properties of an element from the array of class instances ?

Comment: Post real code. Not some invalid pseudo-code. You're probably not understanding asynchronism.

Comment: I can't post the real code. Not sure what do you refer by asynchronism, the data is fetched, the `a` array is populated

Comment: I don't ask you to post **the** real code. I ask you to post real code, that reproduces the problem. I refer to asynchronism because in 99% of the cases, fetching data consists in sending an request, and passing a callback that will populate the property once the response is available, asynchronously. In the meantime, your component is displayed and the array is still empty. If your obscure "fetch data to a" looks like someFunction().suscribe(data => ...) or someFunction().then(data => ...), it's most probably asynchronous. If it were synchronous, you would just do this.a = someFunction().

Comment: it's asynchronous, I subscribe to an observable returned by the `http.get` service. If i `console.log(a[1].a_text)` somewhere in the X class, i got the text in the logs. but if i place `a[1].a_text` in the template, it fails.

Comment: So you have your answer. When you go to a restaurant and ask for a meal, you can't start eating immediately after: you would look really weird trying to eat without food. You can only start eating when the waiter gets back with the food. In the meantime, you're already at your table, but you can't eat. Same here: the component is already displayed, but the data it needs is not available yet. So you need to avoid trying to access the elements of the array (the food) until it's available. That's asynchronism.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation, thanks. I updated the code a bit to illustrate the question more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to confirm you have two elements in the array `a` first.
maybe `*ngFor` is recommended or just check the length before display.

`<div *ngIf="a.length > 1"> {{ a[1].a_text }} </div>`

---

since you are using `asynchronous` call, I think you should use `ngZone.run` or `async` pipe to let angular rerender after you get data back.

And I recommend moving initialize(fetch data) from `constructor` to `ngOnInit`.

---

**Additional**

I have made a quick [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4IgguK1XBaaLjkA9PNlu?p=preview) for you. Maybe you can find the different parts.

Comment: the `a` array is populated with the objects (instances of A), i can see them in the console. if i try to display in the template only `{{ a[0] }}`, i get displayed `[Object object]`, it's present.

Comment: @mazs I think you have to use `ngFor` to show your Array dynamically.

Comment: @mazs you are displaying the second item of the array, can you confirm you have it in your array?

Comment: tried to move the fetch to `ngOnInit` but it didn't help. i updated the code a bit to illustrate better the question. I create the array and a stndalone object from it in the constructor. I display them in the same template, the array fails, the standalone not.

Comment: @mazs have you used ngIf as the answer suggests, in order to avoid accessing the food until it's available, i.e. avoiding to display the content of the array until its size is at least 1?

Comment: @mazs add a sample plunker, check what's the difference please.

Comment: the `ngIf` made the difference it looks like. I still don't understand though how `b` (which is created from `a[0]`) is displayed but `a[0]` not. also `a` is the result of a data processing, it's not directly from the observable...

Comment: @mazs for asynchronous calls, you can not get the data immediately, and angular don't know what you do with the data, it just thows an error while find nothing to render.